# AddressBook synchronization in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, addressbook

Is there any way in iOS to get notification about address book changes since the last time applications was opened.

The application stores address book in internal database and I don't want to perform full sync each time it activated.

Thanks in advance.

Small addition to clarify the question:
I use ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback to observe changes when application suspended to background, but from what I know, this method can't work if application was closed completely and reopened(for example: after phone restart or closed from task list).

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for sync problem?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for this:

[ABAddressBook Reference - ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback)

You should register that notification!

Tell me if worked or if you need any help

**Mário**

Comment: This will work only while application is running(or suspended in bg) and registered to this callback. I want to get notification even if application was closed completely.

Comment: I was searching for a creation date but I think that doesn't exist. In my opinion the best solution is to revert your data each time that the user starts the app and register a notification if the Address Book was changed while the app is running. More info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007099

Comment: Yeap, I looked for it too, but thought maybe I missed something. Full sync could be painful if iPhone contains 10k addressbook entries.

Comment: I will save the last sync time.and when open my app,I will check the sync time and the record last modified time ,so I will know after my last sync,which record has been modified. hope this help.

Comment: But, how can i get last modified time of each record in faster way ?
I am stuck with samething http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759863/how-whatsapp-get-updated-contacts-from-addressbook-faster-in-ios