# How whatsapp get updated contacts from addressbook faster in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, whatsapp, addressbookui

**My findings**

I am designing a logic to sync contact with my Backend. I gone through some apps that doing same thing in IOS. I will take the example of WhatsApp, I found that When I update any contact in Native Addressbook, it reflect that change into Whatsapp withing a fraction.

**My Concern**

I just want to know that how it is syncing in a very faster way. Even a new contact gets synced with its Remote server and get displayed on contact, and with the ability to initiate Whatsapp chat if that number is registered one.

**Summary of Queries**

So, in nutshell my queries are,

1. How Whatsapp is syncing the contact?
2. How whatsapp is getting just updated contact list from Native Addressbook (if it's doing so) ?
3. How whatsapp is just getting just new Contact added in addressbook, is there anything that manages like timestamp or anything else?

I know the following things are there like,

```
ABAddressBookGetPersonCount
ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID
ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople
```

Using the `ABAddressBookGetPersonCount` i can know if any new contacts are there but still how i will be able to know its Record ID without iterating each contact using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople`

So i am just asking for the way to get **just updated list.**

Comment: May I know what's wrong with the Question, and why it deserve downvote ?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I too want to know about this!

Comment: Have you find any solution, i also need to update contact in my app, if native contact is updated, i am using cncontact for now ? @Mrug

Comment: @ArpitBParekh did you find a solution?

Comment: @Mrug  did you find a solution?

Comment: @Aditya did you find a solution?

Comment: i have not implemented, may check below anwer of DanielT @A.s.ALI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is by [registering an external change callback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback). This way, your app will be notified of any changes to the address book as soon as they happen.